# a unique identifier for each device on ios8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I need to have a unique identifier for each device in ios ios8 before 7 serialnumber used but no longer works, I can use ?? that is unique and does not change the desistalar the application and reinstall. always be the same

Comment: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save small data items in the Keychain and they will persist even if the app is deleted and re-installed.

On app launch retrieve the if serial number, if the serial number does not exist in the Keychain create a UUID and save it in the Keychain. Use a Keychain `key` such as "SerialNumber".

The UUID will exist across de-installs and re-installsfor the duration on that device and is guaranteed to be unique across all space and time.

Answer (score 0):

solution

create keychain

H=

## import

@interface SimpleKeychain : NSObject

- (void)save:(NSString *)service data:(id)data;
- (id)load:(NSString *)service;
- (void)delete:(NSString *)service;

@end

M=

## import "SimpleKeychain.h"

@implementation SimpleKeychain

- (NSMutableDictionary *)getKeychainQuery:(NSString *)service {
  return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge id)kSecClass,
          service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrService,
          service, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount,
          (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible,
          nil];
  }
- (void)save:(NSString *)service data:(id)data {
  NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
  SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
  [keychainQuery setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:data] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
  SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, NULL);
  }
- (id)load:(NSString *)service {
  id ret = nil;
  NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
  [keychainQuery setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
  [keychainQuery setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
  CFDataRef keyData = NULL;
  if (SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&keyData) == noErr) {
      @try {
          ret = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)keyData];
      }
      @catch (NSException *e) {
          NSLog(@"Unarchive of %@ failed: %@", service, e);
      }
      @finally {}
  }
  if (keyData) CFRelease(keyData);
  return ret;
  }
- (void)delete:(NSString *)service {
  NSMutableDictionary *keychainQuery = [self getKeychainQuery:service];
  SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keychainQuery);
  }

@end